# Why won't Photoshop CC let me increase my font size beyond 18 px?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I just tried to change a font size of a text layer in Photoshop, and this dialog appeared:

> A value between 0.00 pixel and 18.00 Pixels is required.  Closest value inserted.

No explanation is given. What is the problem?

I'm using an up-to-date Adobe Photoshop CC.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbDeu.png)

Answer (score 4):

(Answering my own question...)

It turns out the PSD was set with a print resolution of 1 pixel/inch. So although the canvas was only 500px wide (and it was intended web graphics), Photoshop was thinking of it as a gigantic 500 inch piece of paper. So an 18px font actually meant 18 inches. And apparently this would take it above what Photoshop considers a reasonable font size.

Solution: change the print resolution in Image Size, but keep the actual pixel dimensions unchanged.

Comment: You saved my bacon. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

for PS CC goto menu Image/Image Size/
unclick Resample and you will find the resolution 1. Change this to 72 and hit OK. 
Now you can play. Just worked for me on one of my images an hour ago.